# Как получать конкретные данные из сервера?

Tags: python, requests, get

Я написал простой код клиента, с помощью его я отправляю запрос на сервер и хочу получить данные: Пользователь: текст. Как мне это сделать работая с библиотекой request?

Код клиента:

```
import requests


data = {'user':'' ,'text' : '' }
payload = {'some': 'data'}
response = requests.get('http://xx.xx.x.x:xxxx/getmessages',params=data, stream=False)
if response:
    print('Соединение установлено')
else:
    print('Соединение потерянно')
print(response.text)
```

Видите ли, я создаю веб чат сервер который соединен по локальному соединению. На одном компьютере написан код сервера, а на другом код клиента. Отправлять данные на сервер у меня получается. А вот принимать данные, чтобы они показывались в консоли - нет. Поэтому я прошу помощи и хочу узнать как принять данные отправленные с другого клиента на сервер и вывести их в консоли visual code

Comment: вместо xx нормальный адрес, соединение проходит успешно

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что именно у вас не получается - передать данные на сервер или обработать ответ? Чтобы передать данные нужно знать, в каком виде сервер ожидает данные. Чтобы обработать ответ, нужно знать, в каком виде сервер возвращает данные. Вы не дали никакой информации.

Comment: @CrazyElf сервер принимает данные в виде "/newmessage?user=ivan&text=msg", отправить запрос на сервер у меня получается (не в этом коде)

Comment: Ну, всё должно работать. А у вас что, не работает?

Comment: @CrazyElf видите ли, я создаю веб чат сервер который соединен по локальному соединению. На одном компьютере написан код сервера, а на другом код клиента. Отправлять данные на сервер у меня получается. А вот принимать данные, чтобы они показывались в консоли - нет. Поэтому я прошу помощи и хочу узнать как принять данные отправленные с другого клиента на сервер и вывести их в консоли visual code

Comment: Что выводится в response.text?

Comment: @CrazyElf 
`['ваня', 'привет', '2021-11-11 09:46:23', 'a', 'f', '2021-11-11 09:46:35', 'CrazyElf', 'ну ты дурак', '2021-11-11 09:47:26']`

Comment: Там точно список, а не `json` какой-нибудь? Что если вывести `print(response.json())`?

Comment: Добавил в свой ответ разбор списка из ответа сервера

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, всё работает. Можете проверить на тестовом сервере:

```
import requests

data = {'user':'user' ,'text' : 'text' }
response = requests.get('https://httpbin.org/get', params=data)
print(response.status_code)
print(response.text)
```

Вывод (сервер сообщает, с какими параметрами он был запрошен):

```
200
{
  "args": {
    "text": "text", 
    "user": "user"
  }, 
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/2.23.0", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-618cb96c-29658f8054159dc3516cd41d"
  }, 
  "origin": "34.72.106.111", 
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/get?user=user&text=text"
}
```

Как видно, запрос к серверу был такой, как вы и хотели:

```
https://httpbin.org/get?user=user&text=text
```

Насчёт того, как разобрать ответ. С вашим примером того, что в `response.text`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

response_text = "['ваня', 'привет', '2021-11-11 09:46:23', 'a', 'f', '2021-11-11 09:46:35', 'CrazyElf', 'и тебе привет', '2021-11-11 09:47:26']"
response_list = literal_eval(response_text)
for i in range(0, len(response_list), 3):
    user, text, dt = response_list[i:i+3]
    print(f'[{dt}] <{user}> {text}')
```

Вывод:

```
[2021-11-11 09:46:23] <ваня> привет
[2021-11-11 09:46:35] <a> f
[2021-11-11 09:47:26] <CrazyElf> и тебе привет
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое!